# I don't know what error is this it is flask and with url_for function

Tags: python, flask

my dir looks like this

```
/static
    /styles
        - login.css
```

my python code is

```
@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")
```

and my HTML is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for("static", filename = "\styles\login.css" ) }} " >
```

when my CSS was not rendering I checked page source code and it's like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles%5Clogin.css " >
```

what should I do to contact NASA?

Comment: Try to replace `backslash` by `slash` => `filename="/styles/login.css"`

Comment: You could also try using different quotation marks like so: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = '/styles/login.css' ) }} " >`.

Answer (score 0):

The input of the css file should be: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'styles/login.css' ) }} " >`

The problem ist that with the double quotation marks before `static` you closed the ones right after `href`

In one of my projects I have a structure like:

```
/static
    /css
        - base.css
        - home.css
```

and I import base.css with the following code:

```html
 <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/base.css')}}"
    />
```

Comment: I am getting the same error still

Comment: And using / instead of \ did not help either?

Comment: I got it. I don't know how, but it works. thx